# Gráfico de dispersão com Histogramas marginais

Tags: r, gráfico, histograma, gráfico-de-dispersão

Gostaria de saber se há uma maneira de se fazer um gráfico semelhante a este no R:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível fazer um plot de dispersão e ao lado ou embaixo, como apresenta a imagem, colocar o histograma representando os dados?

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nesse artigo](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html). Você pode utilizar as funções [`par`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html) e [`layout`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/layout.html) para combinar arranjos de gráficos. Não sei se é possível tunar a apresentação para o seu caso, mas com certeza é possível combinar múltiplos gráficos.

Comment: Oi david, bem-vindo ao site. Você tem algo pronto que possa incluir na pergunta para facilitar o trabalho de quem for te ajudar? Creio que o mais importante seria acrescentar dados de exemplo. Sugiro a leitura desta [pergunta+resposta sobre como perguntar sobre R](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r). Obrigado!

Comment: Obrigado amigos, vou organizar melhor minha pergunta e a posto novamente aqui.

Comment: David, não precisa repostar, basta [edit]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sim, tem como.

No fundo é só questão de arrumar a disposição dos gráficos na tela. Se você acessar o help da função `layout` (`?layout`), lá tem um exemplo justamente de gráfico de dispersão com histogramas marginais (último exemplo do help):

```
x <- pmin(3, pmax(-3, stats::rnorm(50)))
y <- pmin(3, pmax(-3, stats::rnorm(50)))
xhist <- hist(x, breaks = seq(-3,3,0.5), plot = FALSE)
yhist <- hist(y, breaks = seq(-3,3,0.5), plot = FALSE)
top <- max(c(xhist$counts, yhist$counts))
xrange <- c(-3, 3)
yrange <- c(-3, 3)
nf <- layout(matrix(c(2,0,1,3),2,2,byrow = TRUE), c(3,1), c(1,3), TRUE)
layout.show(nf)

par(mar = c(3,3,1,1))
plot(x, y, xlim = xrange, ylim = yrange, xlab = "", ylab = "")
par(mar = c(0,3,1,1))
barplot(xhist$counts, axes = FALSE, ylim = c(0, top), space = 0)
par(mar = c(3,0,1,1))
barplot(yhist$counts, axes = FALSE, xlim = c(0, top), space = 0, horiz = TRUE)

par(def.par)  #- reset to default
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O ideal é você criar uma função baseada no código acima. Tem um pacote no R com uma função praticamente igual a este código:

```
install.packages("UsingR")
library(UsingR)
simple.scatterplot(x,y)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estes exemplos são com os gráficos base. Você também pode fazer isso com o `ggplot2`, conforme dicas [desta pergunta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545035/scatterplot-with-marginal-histograms-in-ggplot2). Para arrumar gráficos do ggplot, [você pode usar o `grid.arrange`, conforme exemplos desta pergunta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33959/como-colocar-gr%C3%A1ficos-diferentes-do-ggplot2-separados-mas-na-mesma-tela)

Um exemplo com `ggplot2`:

```
df <- data.frame(x, y)

library(ggplot2)
adj <- theme(legend.position = "none",          
             axis.title.x = element_blank(),
             axis.title.y = element_blank(),
             axis.text.x = element_blank(),
             axis.text.y = element_blank())

hist_top <- ggplot(df, aes(x)) + geom_histogram() + theme_bw() + adj 
hist_right <- ggplot(df, aes(y)) + geom_histogram()+coord_flip() + theme_bw() + adj 
scatter <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y))+geom_point() + theme_bw()

empty <- ggplot()+geom_point(aes(1,1), colour="white")+
  theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(), 
        panel.background=element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(),           
        axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank())

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(hist_top, empty, scatter, hist_right, ncol=2, nrow=2, widths=c(4, 1), heights=c(1, 4))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]